# Pushing data into in array Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have the following code where I make a loop to get data and send that data to a select .

I'm trying to save this data in an array and then display that data in a `select`
apparently the error comes from the line `newOptions.push ({v.c_group: v.c_codigo_group});` since it asks me for a string , I think

here my code.

```
        case <?php   echo "'".$row["c_codigo_producto"]."'";   ?>:
            $("#divhidden").first().show("fast", function() {});
              var newOptions = {};
            $.ajax({
                data: {
                    'valor': valor
                },
                url: 'JSON/search_group.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {

                $.each(data, function(k, v) {
                  newOptions.push({ v.c_group : v.c_codigo_group });
              });

              },
                async: false,
            });


            var $el = $('#grupo');
            $el.html(' ');
            $.each(newOptions, function(key, value) {
                $el.append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", value).text(key));
            });

            break;
            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: `newOptions` is initialized as an `Object`, not an `Array`. You can't use `push` on an `Object`. Try `newOptions["v.c_group"] = v.c_codigo_group;`.

Comment: `newOptions = {}` makes `newOptions` into an object, not an array. This means it doesn't have a `push` method. I think you mean `newOptions = []` instead

Comment: Why do you mix PHP and JS? What exactly does PHP do, and what is the significance in terms of this question?

Comment: `case <?php   echo "'".$row["c_codigo_producto"]."'";   ?>:` can be simplified to just `case '<?= $row['c_codigo_producto'] ?>':`

Comment: @AndroidNoobie in the select text I see `v.c_group` but the value work great and I can only see one option